# Passing an array to a nested jQuery template

Tags: templates, nested, jquery-templates

I'm using nested jQuery templates - simply one inside the other.

In the inner template I want to loop through an array, Transactions, which is passed to the template. I had this as a single template and it worked fine but because I want to re-use some functionality I split it into two templates. And now I get the error "*c.tmpl is not a function*".

In the outer template I have

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
        ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{tmpl(Transactions) "#AccountTabs_TransRow"}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And in the inner template, AccountTabs_TransRow

```
{{each(idxTr, tr) Transactions}}
<tr>
    {{each(idxTrV, trV) Transactions[idxTr].Values}}
        <td>
            ${FriendlyValue}
        </td>
    {{/each}}
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

The object I'm passing in looks like this (psuedo-code)

```
object
{
    Transactions[]
    {
        Values[]
        {
            FriendlyValue
        }
    }
}
```

If I simply swap the {{tmpl(Trans...  in the outer template with the entire contents of the inner template then it works, but I can't figure out how to split this into two templates.

My suspicion is that it has something to do with the way I'm referencing the array, however having tried different options I've got nowhere.

Can anyone help?